# My PC got got high Electric Power and burned my Gpu‚Cpu and motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, desktop-computer, computer-building

The electricity turned on/off 4 times in the building. My PC shutdown once. After a couple hours, I tried to start my PC, but it didn't start. I went to a PC hardware expert who said my:

- GPU (Gtx1660Ti)
- CPU (i5 9400f)
- Motherboard (Aorus b360 Gaming 3 wifi)

are all not receiving power. Why did my power supply not get damaged first and prevent the other components from getting damaged since the power supply receives power first and supplies it to all PC components?

The memory (RAM) is fine, the power supply (`Gigabyte p550w 80 bronze`) is fine, and the HDD is fine. I managed to fix my motherboard - it was under warranty. While the CPU and GPU both have a warranty, I'm in Egypt and I purchased them in UK - which is very far away. Intel and Gigabyte don't exist in Egypt. Is there a way to fix them? If I managed to go to the UK,  what are the steps to fix them?

Comment: You wrote over 200 words without a single full stop `.`! If you want people to read your question, then make it readable. Paragraphs help a lot too. Use the [Edit] button.

Comment: You should be using a decent surge protector (not the cheapest one you can find). A power surge can destroy capacitors. There's a difference between not receiving power and being damaged. According to what you said in your post, the technician never stated that the CPU/GPU were damaged - the CPU / GPU won't work if the motherboard isn't working. Examine your GPU and see if you notice any bulging or burnt capacitors. I'm surprised that the motherboard was covered under warranty since the issue was caused by a power surge.

Comment: Thx for Reply but I did sent my MB to warranty and it works well now. After it they said CPU/GPU doesn't work anymore they tried to test other CPU/GPU and both of them worked in my MB. But my own CPU/GPU Doesn't Work. they don't know if it's damaged or not Receiving Power?